# How to replicate ellipsis button style in Microsoft Weather App? - (Windows 10)

Tags: win-universal-app

I want to do exactly like the top app bar in the Microsoft weather app.  On the home page top app bar (Forecast page) there is an ellipsis button that when you click on it, the buttons expand downward to show the text description of the buttons - in this case the add to favorites button.

I tried using a flyout, but the effect is totally different.

Furthermore using a regular CommandBar with AppBar buttons achieves a similar result, but the entire width of the CommandBar expands and contracts - whereas I only want the portion that contains the text to expand and contract.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your root of the Page:

```
<CommandBar VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Testing"/>
</CommandBar>
```

Comment: thanks it works, but it has to go inside something like a grid